# Is Ryder Azadi based on Ryder Windham?

Tags: star-wars, inspiration, star-wars-rebels

[Ryder Windham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryder_Windham) is one of the most prolific *Star Wars* authors out there, having written dozens of *Star Wars* books, including some [fairly recently](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ezra%27s_Gamble). The character [Ryder Azadi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ryder_Azadi) on *Star Wars: Rebels* shares the same first name, right down to the unusual spelling. *Star Wars* is no stranger to character names transparently based on *Star Wars* content producers, from *Luke* Skywalker himself to [Gooti Terez](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gooti_Terez).

**Is there any evidence that *Ryder* Azadi is based on *Ryder* Windham?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Absolutely

I contacted Ryder Windham by email, and he responded to my query:

> **Q**: You’ve written a lot of Star Wars books (over sixty), which makes you a prominent figure in the Star Wars community. Star Wars has often named characters after content producers (e.g. Gooti Terez).  Was the character Ryder Azadi on Star Wars: Rebels based on or named after you?
>
> **A**: Henry Gilroy, the co-executive producer of Star Wars Rebels, told me
>   that he named that character after me.

After searching through his emails, he was able to find a quote from Henry Gilroy:

> You probably know this… but in case you don’t… I named a [heroic rebel
>   freedom fighter](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ryder_Azadi) after you in the Rebels series.  I wanted him to look
>   more like you, so we used some white hair for you – and make him a
>   more rugged version of you…  He’s like North Face Ryder.  I hope he
>   gets an action figure.

Comment: A very nice find and worthy of a bounty.

Comment: It's crazy how these smaller scale authors are happy to answer emails. It's really cool.

Comment: @Edlothiad - As was pointed out in another answer, JRR Tolkien was listed in the phone book and was happy to chat with fans until his books were published in the States and he started getting calls at 3am